# What is the use of data-role="fieldcontain"?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I just discovered that text inputs within a div with `data-role="fieldcontain"` don't expand to the 100%, but if you place a text input outside of a fieldcontain it expands to the fullest. This is a bug that they are fixing, but meanwhile...

So I was wondering what is the use of that `data-role="fieldcontain"` in the first place? Why to put it? I saw it on the documents and I just put it in my html, but what is the use of putting it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's a Field Container for Grouping and Display

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html

> **Field container**
>  Container with data-role="fieldcontain" wrapped around label/form element pair
>   
>   **Controlgroup**
>  DIV or FIELDSET container with `data-role="controlgroup"`. Visually integrate multiple button-styled
>   inputs of a single type (checkboxes, link-based buttons, radio
>   buttons, selects) into a group. For grouping form checkboxes and radio
>   buttons, the fieldset container is recommended inside a div container
>   with the `data-role="fieldcontain"`, to improve label styling.
>
> `data-mini`   true | false - Compact sized version for all items in the
>   controlgroup
> `data-type` horizontal | vertical - For horizontal or
>   vertical item alignment

Comment: so if you are not using a label it's completely useless.

Answer (score 5):

As of jquerymobile 1.4 `data-role="fieldcontain"` is deprecated!

use `class="ui-field-contain"` instead.

see release notes http://jquerymobile.com/changelog/1.4.0/

Comment: demo: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/textinput/ - scroll down to 'Fieldcontain' and then resize browser